# Get notified after axios timeout

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, axios, es6-promise

I have an API call using axios. A timeout is set for 2500 millis. What I want is axios to return a value after the timeout so I can notify to the user the request  is aborted due to some server or network error.

How I initialized the timeout

```
const instance = axios.create();
instance.defaults.timeout = 2500;
```

Below is the function that should return a value after the timeout

```
_post(url, body, token) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            instance
                .post(url, body, {headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }})
                .then(data => {
                    resolve(data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 44):

Axios errors are identified by [`code` property](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v0.18.0/lib/core/enhanceError.js#L16).

It's [`ECONNABORTED` code](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v0.18.0/lib/adapters/http.js#L216) in case of a timeout.

The code above uses promise construction antipattern. There's already a promise, no need to create a new one:

```
_post(url, body, token) {
    return instance
        .post(url, body, {headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }})
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED')
                return 'timeout';
            else
                throw error;
        });
}
```

Comment: Well this method does not show any errors after 2.5 seconds.

Comment: It's unknown whether there are timeouts in your case. But it does, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yENBmR?editors=1010 .

Answer (score 5):

I know that this is an old post but I had the same problem  and the following may help others

I could not get the codepen example above to run

In my case I put the timeout on the axios class rather than the instance

```
axios.defaults.timeout = 30000
axios.defaults.timeoutErrorMessage='timeout'
```

I suspect that the reason that you didn't get an error out of it was that you were still looking at e.response.data, in your error handler which presumably gets called at a higher level. On the error object e, e.response.data, does not exist in the case of a timeout so accessing this causes an error in your error handler - at least that is what happened in my case.

With the above I can just check for if(e.message == 'timeout') and then display a special error message

Comment: Not sure about that but from the documentation they right about clarifyTimeoutError.