# JavaScript HTTP POST Request: Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, http, error-handling, fetch

In my Project i am working with different servers (actually vehicles) with different ip adresses. Each vehicle has a list of all vehicles and their ip adresses. I am trying to initialize the vehicles on a map in a for loop.
In this for loop i am sending a Post Request to "http:ipOfVehicle:port:/get_position"

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
```

Everything is working fine, but if the first vehicle is offline it wont initialize even one vehicle. And after a while i get the **Failed to load resource** error (in Safari) or the **net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT** error (in Chrome)

I tried different Methods like try-catch, aborting with the AbortController() and also first checking if the server is reachable with npm is-reachable, but nothing is working.

I would be really glad if someone could help me out :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If the server is offline you will get the error, it's expected.

Comment: If it is possible one of the ip addresses is offline, you have to build a mechanism that sets a timeout to every connection and updates the position when vehicle is again available.

Comment: @Georgy my goal is to catch the timeout error in an acceptable time, so that it doesn't take 10+ seconds for the timeout to occur.

Comment: @dariosicily Thank you, but for that I need to catch the timeout error and I don't know how to.

Comment: You are welcome, [get-notified-after-axios-timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619928/get-notified-after-axios-timeout) is an example and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) contains an example of configuration with timeout.

Comment: Thank you @dariosicily. That helped me a lot. Now I can detect a timeout. Now I want to get the timeout after a specified time, lets say 2 seconds. How do I realize this with axios?

Comment: Okay got it right after I wrote the last comment ^^
Its just `instance.defaults.timeout = 2000`